# Android ndk issues socket and std issues

Tags: android, c++, std, min, android-ndk

I am trying to compile my socket lib for the NDK and I am getting the following two errors:

```
error: 'close' was not declared in this scope
```

AND

```
error: 'min' is not a member of 'std'
```

I have followed the steps outlined [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339229/android-std-and-stl-support) to fix the latter to no avail and I am not sure about the first. Ive imported the following libs:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
```

Can ANYONE help me? I'm slowly losing my mind. Each build error I fix, more seem to appear. I am SO close to getting this to work.....

Also, I HAVE read the relevant ndk docs. Ive tried both gnustl_shared and stlport_shared as the APP_STL: value in my Application.mk file.

Just as a reference, you can get the source code [HERE](https://github.com/nterry/39DLL-4-Linux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::min`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) requires `#include <algorithm>`. [`close`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/close.html) requires `#include <unistd.h>`.

When you get an error like this, check the documentation for the function and see what header file(s) it requires.

Comment: I have read the docs. I may not have read the right doc in the docs/ dir though...

In either case, THANKS!!!!! You are my hero! Worked like a charm.