# NDK ndk-build error

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am getting the following list of errors when I try to perform an NDK build...
Any one has any clue?

```
encies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:153: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:153: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfPizCompressor.o): In function `std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<Imf::Name const, Imf::Channel> >::operator++()':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/NDK/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/bits/stl_tree.h:259: undefined reference to `std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*)'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfPizCompressor.o): In function `PizCompressor':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfPizCompressor.cpp:228: undefined reference to `__cxa_end_cleanup'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfPizCompressor.o):(.ARM.extab.text._ZN3Imf13PizCompressorC2ERKNS_6HeaderEjj+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfPizCompressor.o): In function `std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<Imf::Name const, Imf::Channel> >::operator++()':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/NDK/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/bits/stl_tree.h:259: undefined reference to `std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*)'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfPizCompressor.o): In function `PizCompressor':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfPizCompressor.cpp:228: undefined reference to `__cxa_end_cleanup'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfPizCompressor.o):(.ARM.extab.text._ZN3Imf13PizCompressorC1ERKNS_6HeaderEjj+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfPizCompressor.o):(.data.rel.ro+0x28): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfPxr24Compressor.o): In function `Imf::(anonymous namespace)::notEnoughData()':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfPxr24Compressor.cpp:165: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfPxr24Compressor.cpp:165: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfPxr24Compressor.o): In function `unsigned int Imf::uiAdd<unsigned int>(unsigned int, unsigned int)':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:105: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:105: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfPxr24Compressor.o): In function `std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<Imf::Name const, Imf::Channel> >::operator++()':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/NDK/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/bits/stl_tree.h:259: undefined reference to `std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*)'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfPxr24Compressor.o): In function `tooMuchData':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfPxr24Compressor.cpp:173: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfPxr24Compressor.cpp:173: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfPxr24Compressor.o): In function `Imf::Pxr24Compressor::uncompress(char const*, int, Imath::Box<Imath::Vec2<int> >, char const*&)':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfPxr24Compressor.cpp:431: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfPxr24Compressor.o): In function `std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<Imf::Name const, Imf::Channel> >::operator++()':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/NDK/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/bits/stl_tree.h:259: undefined reference to `std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*)'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfPxr24Compressor.o): In function `Imf::Pxr24Compressor::compress(char const*, int, Imath::Box<Imath::Vec2<int> >, char const*&)':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfPxr24Compressor.cpp:404: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfPxr24Compressor.cpp:404: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfPxr24Compressor.o): In function `Pxr24Compressor':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfPxr24Compressor.cpp:206: undefined reference to `__cxa_end_cleanup'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfPxr24Compressor.o):(.ARM.extab.text._ZN3Imf15Pxr24CompressorC1ERKNS_6HeaderEjj+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfPxr24Compressor.o): In function `Pxr24Compressor':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfPxr24Compressor.cpp:206: undefined reference to `__cxa_end_cleanup'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfPxr24Compressor.o):(.ARM.extab.text._ZN3Imf15Pxr24CompressorC2ERKNS_6HeaderEjj+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfPxr24Compressor.o): In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/NDK/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/iostream:72: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfPxr24Compressor.o): In function `global constructors keyed to ImfPxr24Compressor.cpp':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfPxr24Compressor.cpp:550: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfPxr24Compressor.o):(.data.rel.ro+0x28): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfRleCompressor.o): In function `Imf::RleCompressor::uncompress(char const*, int, int, char const*&)':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfRleCompressor.cpp:283: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfRleCompressor.cpp:283: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfRleCompressor.o): In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/NDK/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/iostream:72: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfRleCompressor.o): In function `global constructors keyed to ImfRleCompressor.cpp':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfRleCompressor.cpp:331: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfRleCompressor.o): In function `uiMult<unsigned int>':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:69: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:69: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfRleCompressor.o): In function `RleCompressor':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfRleCompressor.cpp:170: undefined reference to `__cxa_end_cleanup'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfRleCompressor.o):(.ARM.extab.text._ZN3Imf13RleCompressorC2ERKNS_6HeaderEj+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfRleCompressor.o): In function `RleCompressor':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfRleCompressor.cpp:170: undefined reference to `__cxa_end_cleanup'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfRleCompressor.o):(.ARM.extab.text._ZN3Imf13RleCompressorC1ERKNS_6HeaderEj+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfRleCompressor.o):(.data.rel.ro+0x28): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfZipCompressor.o): In function `Imf::ZipCompressor::uncompress(char const*, int, int, char const*&)':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfZipCompressor.cpp:192: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfZipCompressor.cpp:192: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfZipCompressor.o): In function `Imf::ZipCompressor::compress(char const*, int, int, char const*&)':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfZipCompressor.cpp:159: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfZipCompressor.cpp:159: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfZipCompressor.o): In function `ZipCompressor':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfZipCompressor.cpp:76: undefined reference to `__cxa_end_cleanup'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfZipCompressor.o):(.ARM.extab.text._ZN3Imf13ZipCompressorC1ERKNS_6HeaderEjj+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfZipCompressor.o): In function `ZipCompressor':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfZipCompressor.cpp:76: undefined reference to `__cxa_end_cleanup'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfZipCompressor.o):(.ARM.extab.text._ZN3Imf13ZipCompressorC2ERKNS_6HeaderEjj+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfZipCompressor.o): In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/NDK/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/iostream:72: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfZipCompressor.o): In function `global constructors keyed to ImfZipCompressor.cpp':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfZipCompressor.cpp:240: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfZipCompressor.o):(.data.rel.ro+0x28): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(IlmThread.o): In function `IlmThread::Thread::start()':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmThread/IlmThread.cpp:74: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmThread/IlmThread.cpp:74: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(IlmThread.o): In function `~Thread':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmThread/IlmThread.cpp:67: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmThread/IlmThread.cpp:67: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmThread/IlmThread.cpp:67: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmThread/IlmThread.cpp:67: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(IlmThread.o): In function `Thread':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmThread/IlmThread.cpp:61: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmThread/IlmThread.cpp:61: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmThread/IlmThread.cpp:61: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmThread/IlmThread.cpp:61: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(IlmThread.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN3Iex9NoImplExcE[typeinfo for Iex::NoImplExc]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(IlmThread.o):(.data.rel.ro+0x14): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfB44Compressor.o): In function `std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<Imf::Name const, Imf::Channel> >::operator++()':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/NDK/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/bits/stl_tree.h:259: undefined reference to `std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*)'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfB44Compressor.o): In function `Imf::(anonymous namespace)::notEnoughData()':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfB44Compressor.cpp:440: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfB44Compressor.cpp:440: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfB44Compressor.o): In function `std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<Imf::Name const, Imf::Channel> >::operator++()':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/NDK/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/bits/stl_tree.h:259: undefined reference to `std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*)'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfB44Compressor.o): In function `tooMuchData':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfB44Compressor.cpp:448: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfB44Compressor.cpp:448: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfB44Compressor.o): In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/NDK/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/iostream:72: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfB44Compressor.o): In function `global constructors keyed to ImfB44Compressor.cpp':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfB44Compressor.cpp:1069: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfB44Compressor.o): In function `checkArraySize<unsigned int>':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:153: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfCheckedArithmetic.h:153: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfB44Compressor.o): In function `std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<Imf::Name const, Imf::Channel> >::operator++()':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/NDK/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/bits/stl_tree.h:259: undefined reference to `std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*)'
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/NDK/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/bits/stl_tree.h:259: undefined reference to `std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*)'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfB44Compressor.o): In function `B44Compressor':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfB44Compressor.cpp:548: undefined reference to `__cxa_end_cleanup'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfB44Compressor.o):(.ARM.extab.text._ZN3Imf13B44CompressorC2ERKNS_6HeaderEjjb+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfB44Compressor.o): In function `std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<Imf::Name const, Imf::Channel> >::operator++()':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/NDK/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/bits/stl_tree.h:259: undefined reference to `std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*)'
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/NDK/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/bits/stl_tree.h:259: undefined reference to `std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*)'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfB44Compressor.o): In function `B44Compressor':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfB44Compressor.cpp:548: undefined reference to `__cxa_end_cleanup'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfB44Compressor.o):(.ARM.extab.text._ZN3Imf13B44CompressorC1ERKNS_6HeaderEjjb+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfB44Compressor.o):(.data.rel.ro+0x28): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfHuf.o): In function `Imf::(anonymous namespace)::notEnoughData()':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfHuf.cpp:101: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfHuf.cpp:101: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfHuf.o): In function `Imf::(anonymous namespace)::unexpectedEndOfTable()':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfHuf.cpp:125: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfHuf.cpp:125: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfHuf.o): In function `Imf::(anonymous namespace)::tableTooLong()':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfHuf.cpp:133: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfHuf.cpp:133: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfHuf.o): In function `Imf::(anonymous namespace)::invalidTableEntry()':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfHuf.cpp:141: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfHuf.cpp:141: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfHuf.o): In function `Imf::(anonymous namespace)::tooMuchData()':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfHuf.cpp:93: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfHuf.cpp:93: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfHuf.o): In function `Imf::(anonymous namespace)::invalidCode()':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfHuf.cpp:109: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfHuf.cpp:109: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfHuf.o): In function `invalidTableSize':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfHuf.cpp:117: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfHuf.cpp:117: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfHuf.o): In function `invalidNBits':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfHuf.cpp:85: undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfHuf.cpp:85: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfHuf.o): In function `~AutoArray':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfAutoArray.h:61: undefined reference to `__cxa_end_cleanup'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfHuf.o): In function `Imf::hufUncompress(char const*, int, unsigned short*, int)':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfHuf.cpp:1076: undefined reference to `__cxa_begin_catch'
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfHuf.cpp:1079: undefined reference to `__cxa_rethrow'
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/./IlmImf/ImfHuf.cpp:1076: undefined reference to `__cxa_end_catch'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfHuf.o):(.ARM.extab.text._ZN3Imf13hufUncompressEPKciPti+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfHuf.o): In function `~AutoArray':
    D:\Projects.CPP\Engine5\svn\trunk\Dependencies\FreeImage/D:/Projects.CPP/Engine5/svn/trunk/Dependencies/FreeImage/jni/../Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfAutoArray.h:61: undefined reference to `__cxa_end_cleanup'
    ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreeimage.a(ImfHuf.o):(.ARM.extab.text._ZN3Imf11hufCompressEPKtiPc+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
    /home/flock/ANDROID/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/libgcc.a(unwind-arm.o): In function `__gnu_unwind_pr_common':
    /i/ndk-andrewhsieh/src.1-with-cherrypicks//build/../gcc/gcc-4.4.3/libgcc/../gcc/config/arm/unwind-arm.c:1237: undefined reference to `__cxa_call_unexpected'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libimageprocessing.so] Error 1
```

Comment: have you link the stl port ?http://stackoverflow.com/a/7341665/411522

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved the issue by adding an Application.mk with contents as follows-

```
APP_OPTIM := release
APP_PLATFORM := android-7
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS += -frtti 
APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions
APP_CPPFLAGS += -DANDROID
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
```

Answer (score 4):

first of all, you need add 'APP_STL' tag in 'Application.mk':

```
APP_STL := stlport_static #or 'stlport_shared' 'gnustl_static'
```

and then edit 'Android.mk' add link info:

```
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libstlport_static
# or you may need shared library
# LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libstlport_shared
```

it work for me. good luck!

Comment: Part 2 - "and then edit 'Android.mk' add link info:...", is redundant! if you want to use STL X, the Part 1 - APP_STL is only what you need.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered this problem when compiling a boost::thread example. The gnustl_static library must be linked with your program if GNU STL is used. Just add -lgnustl_static to the LOCAL_LDLIBS line in Android.mk. Example:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lgnustl_static
```

For more details, please read https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/Boost-for-Android