# NDK build undefined reference to... on method calls

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, android-ndk, java-native-interface

When i build my Android ndk project from within eclipse i get the following error referencing to a function call using std::string as argument, i get a similar error if i change to const char * arg. How can i get rid of this, my android.mk is attached below the error:

```
/Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/JsonPoco/JsonPoco.o: in function jsonParse:jni/JsonPoco.cpp:23: error: undefined reference to 'StoreRefListComplexType::StoreRefListComplexType(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
ROOT_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)
include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PATH = $(ROOT_PATH)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := eng
LOCAL_ARM_MODE    := arm
LOCAL_MODULE      := JsonPoco # Your own library.
LOCAL_SRC_FILES   := JsonPoco.cpp # Your own library source.
LOCAL_CFLAGS      := -DPOCO_ANDROID -DPOCO_NO_FPENVIRONMENT -DPOCO_NO_WSTRING -DPOCO_NO_SHAREDMEMORY
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS   := -frtti -fexceptions 
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := PocoFoundation \
PocoJSON
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And my Application.mk

```
#Application.mk
APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

The method call looks like this, where test is a std::string:

```
void jsonParse(JNIEnv* aEnv, jobject aObj){
  std::string test= "jsondata...";
  ComplexType* ref = new ComplexType(test);
 }
```

I have defined my jsonParse method as reachable through JNI using a method table:

```
static JNINativeMethod methodTable[] = {
  {"json_parse", "()V", (void *) jsonParse}};
```

and the recieving method/constructor:

```
ComplexType::ComplexType(std::string jsonstring);
```

Comment: We can't help you without the source code.

Comment: added the relevant code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message indicates that some source file or library has been left out of the make file. In my case the file housing: ComplexType was included in the C++ source but not in the make script.

Another problem with a similiar error message, but where a library is missing is displayed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665521/ndk-ndk-build-error).