# fatal error: vector: No such file or directory

Tags: build, android-ndk, compiler-errors, makefile

I have an Android project comprising of lots of native code in C++. However, I am unable to build my library as it is not able to find out vector.h header file. What could be the issue ?
A sample of my inclusions in almost all the pages.

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>
```

The compiler is able to find out all other header files except vector.h in every file. Any suggestions about where am I going wrong ?

NOTE : Filenames end with `.cpp` and I have already tried `#include <vector.h>` , `#include "vector.h"`

Thanks !

Comment: Are you sure you're using a C++ compiler (and not a C one)?

Comment: I am using ndk-build to compile

Comment: @Mat How to ensure that I use C+ compiler to compile ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was finally resolved by creating Application.mk in JNI folder of project and adding the following to it :-

```
APP_STL := stlport_static
```

For more details, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893403/cant-include-c-headers-like-vector-in-android-ndk) question on SO

Comment: sadly, does not fix it for me :(