# Android NDK including stl

Tags: android, android-ndk

Hi I am trying to include STL in one of my projects but it does not work ... I have noticed this thread

many times and seen:

[Can't include C++ headers like vector in Android NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893403/cant-include-c-headers-like-vector-in-android-ndk)

But it does not work for me 
this is my make file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

APP_STL := stlport_static
LOCAL_MODULE    := hellostl
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellostl.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I have also added this to my include diroctories
C:\android-ndk\sources\cxx-stl\stlport\stlport

But it still does not work, I allways get no such file or directory for

```
#include <vector>
```

whenever I try to build

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

`APP_STL := stlport_static`

should be set in Application.mk, not in Android.mk

Or you can set it on command line, e.g.

```
ndk-build APP_STL=stlport_static
```