# android ndk doesn't have maps

Tags: android-ndk, android-ndk-r7

I am cross compiling my some legacy source  code to android , I am using c++ map in my source code .

I am using map to store some object with ID

```
 map<string, object> ; 
 map<"ls/1/uri/2", test> ;
```

Since I dont have map support in android ndk can some body suggest which source lib in the Ndk will help avail the same functionality ..

Comment: There should certainly be `map` support with the NDK. Are you [linking against the STL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4931170/1524450)?

Comment: compilation of this goes fine but in the run time I am getting the Fatal error .  when I tried this  map<string,string> test ; test["Map1"] = "Map";  isn't the proper way to stroe the data in map ?