# Error of string: no such file or sdirectory, in Android NDK r8b build of OpenCV 2.4.2

Tags: opencv, build, android-ndk

I am using Android NDK r8b to build OpenCV 2.4.2.
when I input "make" in the terminal, the error output is:

error: string: No such file or directory
error: vector: No such file or directory.

And other similar errors.

When I use Android NDK r8b to build OpenCV version downloaded in Mar. 2014, building works well.

And after google, it seems the problem with OpenCV 2.4.2 lies in the build cannot find standard libraries.
But I do not know where to include it.

Comment: This [post][1] from StackOverflow should answer your question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893403/cant-include-c-headers-like-vector-in-android-ndk