# Compiling PugiXML with Android NDK

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk, pugixml

I'm trying to compile the PugiXML library with Android NDK; it says on the website that this is possible, but the download doesn't contain an android makefile and I haven't used NDK much before (the docs don't help!)

I'm currently getting the error:

```
/pugiconfig.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I was originally getting an error because NDK couldn't find `#include <iterator>` and I'm not sure I've correctly resolved this. I tried following [this stackoverflow Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893403/cant-include-c-headers-like-vector-in-android-ndk) and ended up with the error shown above.

My current Android.mk looks like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := webface
LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .hpp .cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../pugiconfig.hpp ../pugixml.hpp ../pugixml.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and my current Application.mk looks like this:

```
APP_ABI := all
APP_STL := stlport_shared
```

Comment: I'd suggest removing everything but pugixml.cpp from LOCAL_SRC_FILES. Also, note that if you have issues with <iterator> you can just compile with PUGIXML_NO_STL (probably by adding -DPUGIXML_NO_STL to CXXFLAGS).

Comment: Removing everything but the .cpp worked; if you want to add it as an answer I will mark it correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest removing everything but pugixml.cpp from LOCAL_SRC_FILES.

Also, note that if you have issues with  you can just compile with PUGIXML_NO_STL (by adding -DPUGIXML_NO_STL to CXXFLAGS).