# gradle experimental plugin ndk, stl related problems

Tags: android, c++, stl, android-ndk

I am trying to enable ndk support in android studio, and facing issues related to `mutex` and other headers. I have taken a look at this [Can't include C++ headers like vector in Android NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893403/cant-include-c-headers-like-vector-in-android-ndk?rq=1), but my understanding is that with the experimental plugin, all the settings that were in Android.mk need to be done within `app/build.gradle`

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources, :cpp_example_util:generateDebugSources, :cpp_example_util:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :cpp_example_util:mockableAndroidJar, :cpp_example_util:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :cpp_example_util:compileDebugSources, :cpp_example_util:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :cpp_example_util:compileDebugUnitTestSources]
/home/mihai/Projects/tango-ar/cpp_plane_fitting_example/app/src/main/jni/point_cloud_renderer.cc
Information:(17) (Unknown) In file included
/home/mihai/Projects/tango-ar/cpp_plane_fitting_example/app/src/main/jni/tango-plane-fitting/point_cloud_renderer.h
Error:(20, 17) mutex: No such file or directory
/home/mihai/Projects/tango-ar/tango_client_api/include/tango_client_api.h
Information:(19) (Unknown) In file included
/home/mihai/Projects/tango-ar/third_party/glm/glm/mat2x2.hpp
Information:(31) (Unknown) In file included
/home/mihai/Projects/tango-ar/third_party/glm/glm/detail/type_mat2x2.hpp
/home/mihai/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gabi++/include/cstdint
Information:(37) (Unknown) In file included
/usr/include/stdint.h
Warning:(148) warning: "__INT64_C" redefined
Warning:(149) warning: "__UINT64_C" redefined
Warning:(148) warning: "__INT64_C" redefined
Warning:(149) warning: "__UINT64_C" redefined
Warning:(148) warning: "__INT64_C" redefined
Warning:(149) warning: "__UINT64_C" redefined
/home/mihai/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_algobase.h
Information:(720) (Unknown) In file included
/home/mihai/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_algobase.c
Error:(301, 26) error: 'UCHAR_MAX' was not declared in this scope
Error:(301, 43) error: 'CHAR_BIT' was not declared in this scope
Error:(302, 10) error: '__hints' was not declared in this scope
/home/mihai/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_cprolog.h
Information:(18) (Unknown) In file included
/home/mihai/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_limits.h
Error:(124, 81) error: 'CHAR_BIT' was not declared in this scope
Error:(198, 45) error: 'CHAR_MIN' was not declared in this scope
Error:(198, 55) error: 'CHAR_MAX' was not declared in this scope
Error:(198, 73) error: template argument 2 is invalid
Error:(198, 73) error: template argument 3 is invalid
Error:(204, 52) error: 'SCHAR_MIN' was not declared in this scope
Error:(204, 63) error: 'SCHAR_MAX' was not declared in this scope
Error:(204, 82) error: template argument 2 is invalid
Error:(204, 82) error: template argument 3 is invalid
Error:(210, 57) error: 'UCHAR_MAX' was not declared in this scope
Error:(210, 76) error: template argument 3 is invalid
Error:(224, 46) error: 'SHRT_MIN' was not declared in this scope
Error:(224, 56) error: 'SHRT_MAX' was not declared in this scope
Error:(224, 74) error: template argument 2 is invalid
Error:(224, 74) error: template argument 3 is invalid
Error:(229, 58) error: 'USHRT_MAX' was not declared in this scope
Error:(229, 77) error: template argument 3 is invalid
Error:(239, 44) error: 'INT_MIN' was not declared in this scope
Error:(239, 53) error: 'INT_MAX' was not declared in this scope
Error:(239, 70) error: template argument 2 is invalid
Error:(239, 70) error: template argument 3 is invalid
Error:(244, 56) error: 'UINT_MAX' was not declared in this scope
Error:(244, 74) error: template argument 3 is invalid
Error:(249, 45) error: 'LONG_MIN' was not declared in this scope
Error:(249, 55) error: 'LONG_MAX' was not declared in this scope
Error:(249, 73) error: template argument 2 is invalid
Error:(249, 73) error: template argument 3 is invalid
Error:(254, 57) error: 'ULONG_MAX' was not declared in this scope
Error:(254, 76) error: template argument 3 is invalid
/home/mihai/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/config/features.h
Information:(803, 75) in definition of macro '_STLP_STATIC_CONSTANT'
Information:(311, 66) in definition of macro '_STLP_STATIC_ASSERT'
Information:(583, 51) in definition of macro '__STATIC_CAST'
/home/mihai/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_num_put.c
Information:(26) (Unknown) In file included
Error:(158, 71) error: 'is_signed' is not a member of 'std::numeric_limits<long int>'
Error:(159, 82) error: 'max' is not a member of 'std::numeric_limits<long int>'
Information:(159, 55) in expansion of macro '__STATIC_CAST'
/home/mihai/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_istream.h
Information:(352) (Unknown) In file included
/home/mihai/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_istream.c
Error:(651, 73) error: 'is_signed' is not a member of 'std::numeric_limits<long int>'
Error:(652, 88) error: 'max' is not a member of 'std::numeric_limits<long int>'
Information:(652, 61) in expansion of macro '__STATIC_CAST'
Error:(865, 11) error: 'max' is not a member of 'std::numeric_limits<long int>'
Error:(1110, 33) error: 'max' is not a member of 'std::numeric_limits<long int>'
Error:(1112, 17) error: 'max' is not a member of 'std::numeric_limits<int>'
Error:(1150, 33) error: 'max' is not a member of 'std::numeric_limits<long int>'
Error:(1152, 17) error: 'max' is not a member of 'std::numeric_limits<int>'
/home/mihai/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_algo.c
Information:(34) (Unknown) In file included
/home/mihai/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_tempbuf.h
Error:(89, 30) error: 'INT_MAX' was not declared in this scope
Information:(160) (Unknown) In file included
/home/mihai/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_tempbuf.c
Error:(39, 25) error: 'INT_MAX' was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/MathFunctions.h
Error:(479, 45) error: 'CHAR_BIT' was not declared in this scope
Error:(522, 61) error: template argument 3 is invalid
Error:(522, 61) error: template argument 4 is invalid
Error:(523, 43) error: 'CHAR_BIT' was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h
Error:(277, 16) error: 'move' is not a member of 'std'
Error:(278, 16) error: 'move' is not a member of 'std'
Error:(279, 16) error: 'move' is not a member of 'std'
Error:(336, 16) error: 'move' is not a member of 'std'
Error:(337, 16) error: 'move' is not a member of 'std'
Error:(390, 16) error: 'move' is not a member of 'std'
Error:(391, 16) error: 'move' is not a member of 'std'
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h
Error:(442, 20) error: 'move' is not a member of 'std'
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h
Error:(216, 14) error: 'move' is not a member of 'std'
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core
Information:(259) (Unknown) In file included
Information:(258) (Unknown) In file included
Information:(288) (Unknown) In file included
Information:(293) (Unknown) In file included
Information:(294) (Unknown) In file included
Information:(295) (Unknown) In file included
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Array.h
Error:(129, 14) error: 'move' is not a member of 'std'
/usr/local/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_nullptr_t.hpp
Error:(35, 18) error: 'nullptr_t' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
/usr/local/include/boost/shared_ptr.hpp
Information:(17) (Unknown) In file included
/usr/local/include/boost/config.hpp
Information:(61) (Unknown) In file included
/usr/local/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp
Information:(31) (Unknown) In file included
Error:(340, 45) error: invalid use of '::'
Error:(340, 45) error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
Error:(340, 47) error: expected unqualified-id before 'noexcept'
Error:(365, 63) error: expected ')' before 'p'
Error:(380, 72) error: expected ')' before 'p'
Error:(604, 57) error: declaration of 'operator=' as non-function
Error:(604, 26) error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
Error:(604, 57) error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'sp_nullptr_t' with no type [-fpermissive]
Error:(604, 57) error: invalid use of '::'
Error:(604, 57) error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
Error:(604, 59) error: expected unqualified-id before 'noexcept'
Error:(751, 83) error: 'boost::detail::sp_nullptr_t' has not been declared
Error:(756, 58) error: declaration of 'operator==' as non-function
Error:(756, 43) error: 'sp_nullptr_t' is not a member of 'boost::detail'
Error:(756, 86) error: expected primary-expression before 'const'
Error:(761, 83) error: 'boost::detail::sp_nullptr_t' has not been declared
Error:(766, 58) error: declaration of 'operator!=' as non-function
Error:(766, 43) error: 'sp_nullptr_t' is not a member of 'boost::detail'
Error:(766, 86) error: expected primary-expression before 'const'
/usr/local/include/boost/signals2.hpp
Information:(15) (Unknown) In file included
/usr/local/include/boost/signals2/deconstruct.hpp
Error:(72, 17) error: 'forward' is not a member of 'std'
Error:(72, 34) error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
Error:(299, 22) error: 'forward' is not a member of 'std'
Error:(299, 39) error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
Error:(480, 48) error: 'forward' is not a member of 'std'
Error:(480, 65) error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
/usr/local/include/boost/utility/addressof.hpp
Information:(15) (Unknown) In file included
/usr/local/include/boost/core/addressof.hpp
Error:(58, 18) error: 'nullptr_t' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
Error:(62, 35) error: 'addr_nullptr_t' was not declared in this scope
Error:(62, 50) error: template argument 1 is invalid
Error:(72, 35) error: 'addr_nullptr_t' was not declared in this scope
Error:(72, 56) error: template argument 1 is invalid
Error:(82, 35) error: 'addr_nullptr_t' was not declared in this scope
Error:(82, 59) error: template argument 1 is invalid
Error:(92, 35) error: 'addr_nullptr_t' was not declared in this scope
Error:(92, 65) error: template argument 1 is invalid
/usr/local/include/boost/integer_fwd.hpp
Error:(137, 29) error: 'digits' is not a member of 'std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>'
Error:(137, 29) error: 'digits' is not a member of 'std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>'
Error:(137, 74) error: template argument 1 is invalid
/usr/local/include/boost/integer_traits.hpp
Error:(83, 46) error: 'CHAR_MIN' was not declared in this scope
Error:(83, 56) error: 'CHAR_MAX' was not declared in this scope
Error:(83, 64) error: template argument 2 is invalid
Error:(83, 64) error: template argument 3 is invalid
Error:(89, 53) error: 'SCHAR_MIN' was not declared in this scope
Error:(89, 64) error: 'SCHAR_MAX' was not declared in this scope
Error:(89, 73) error: template argument 2 is invalid
Error:(89, 73) error: template argument 3 is invalid
Error:(95, 58) error: 'UCHAR_MAX' was not declared in this scope
Error:(95, 67) error: template argument 3 is invalid
Error:(131, 47) error: 'SHRT_MIN' was not declared in this scope
Error:(131, 57) error: 'SHRT_MAX' was not declared in this scope
Error:(131, 65) error: template argument 2 is invalid
Error:(131, 65) error: template argument 3 is invalid
Error:(137, 59) error: 'USHRT_MAX' was not declared in this scope
Error:(137, 68) error: template argument 3 is invalid
Error:(143, 45) error: 'INT_MIN' was not declared in this scope
Error:(143, 54) error: 'INT_MAX' was not declared in this scope
Error:(143, 61) error: template argument 2 is invalid
Error:(143, 61) error: template argument 3 is invalid
Error:(149, 57) error: 'UINT_MAX' was not declared in this scope
Error:(149, 65) error: template argument 3 is invalid
Error:(155, 46) error: 'LONG_MIN' was not declared in this scope
Error:(155, 56) error: 'LONG_MAX' was not declared in this scope
Error:(155, 64) error: template argument 2 is invalid
Error:(155, 64) error: template argument 3 is invalid
Error:(161, 58) error: 'ULONG_MAX' was not declared in this scope
Error:(161, 67) error: template argument 3 is invalid
/usr/local/include/boost/function/function_base.hpp
Information:(21) (Unknown) In file included
/usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/type_with_alignment.hpp
Information:(19) (Unknown) In file included
/usr/local/include/boost/integer.hpp
Information:(18) (Unknown) In file included
Information:(20) (Unknown) In file included
Error:(84, 68) error: 'CHAR_BIT' was not declared in this scope
Error:(84, 76) error: template argument 1 is invalid
Error:(85, 72) error: 'CHAR_BIT' was not declared in this scope
Error:(85, 80) error: template argument 1 is invalid
Error:(104, 78) error: 'CHAR_BIT' was not declared in this scope
Error:(104, 86) error: template argument 1 is invalid
Error:(105, 81) error: 'CHAR_BIT' was not declared in this scope
Error:(105, 89) error: template argument 1 is invalid
Error:(117, 7) error: 'CHAR_BIT' was not declared in this scope
Error:(122, 58) error: 'CHAR_BIT' was not declared in this scope
Error:(126, 22) error: 'digits' is not a member of 'std::numeric_limits<long int>'
Error:(127, 22) error: 'digits' is not a member of 'std::numeric_limits<int>'
Error:(128, 22) error: 'digits' is not a member of 'std::numeric_limits<short int>'
Error:(129, 22) error: 'digits' is not a member of 'std::numeric_limits<signed char>'
Error:(130, 9) error: template argument 1 is invalid
Error:(138, 6) error: 'CHAR_BIT' was not declared in this scope
Error:(153, 58) error: 'CHAR_BIT' was not declared in this scope
Error:(157, 20) error: 'digits' is not a member of 'std::numeric_limits<long unsigned int>'
Error:(158, 20) error: 'digits' is not a member of 'std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>'
Error:(159, 20) error: 'digits' is not a member of 'std::numeric_limits<short unsigned int>'
Error:(160, 20) error: 'digits' is not a member of 'std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>'
Error:(161, 9) error: template argument 1 is invalid
Error:(184, 24) error: 'const_max' is not a member of 'boost::integer_traits<long int>'
Error:(185, 24) error: 'const_max' is not a member of 'boost::integer_traits<int>'
Error:(186, 24) error: 'const_max' is not a member of 'boost::integer_traits<short int>'
Error:(187, 24) error: 'const_max' is not a member of 'boost::integer_traits<signed char>'
Error:(188, 9) error: template argument 1 is invalid
Error:(206, 24) error: 'const_min' is not a member of 'boost::integer_traits<long int>'
Error:(207, 24) error: 'const_min' is not a member of 'boost::integer_traits<int>'
Error:(208, 24) error: 'const_min' is not a member of 'boost::integer_traits<short int>'
Error:(209, 24) error: 'const_min' is not a member of 'boost::integer_traits<signed char>'
Error:(210, 9) error: template argument 1 is invalid
Error:(250, 24) error: 'const_max' is not a member of 'boost::integer_traits<long unsigned int>'
Error:(251, 24) error: 'const_max' is not a member of 'boost::integer_traits<unsigned int>'
Error:(252, 24) error: 'const_max' is not a member of 'boost::integer_traits<short unsigned int>'
Error:(253, 24) error: 'const_max' is not a member of 'boost::integer_traits<unsigned char>'
Error:(254, 9) error: template argument 1 is invalid
/usr/local/include/boost/scoped_ptr.hpp
Information:(14) (Unknown) In file included
/usr/local/include/boost/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.hpp
Error:(121, 83) error: 'boost::detail::sp_nullptr_t' has not been declared
Error:(126, 58) error: declaration of 'operator==' as non-function
Error:(126, 43) error: 'sp_nullptr_t' is not a member of 'boost::detail'
Error:(126, 86) error: expected primary-expression before 'const'
Error:(131, 83) error: 'boost::detail::sp_nullptr_t' has not been declared
Error:(136, 58) error: declaration of 'operator!=' as non-function
Error:(136, 43) error: 'sp_nullptr_t' is not a member of 'boost::detail'
Error:(136, 86) error: expected primary-expression before 'const'
/home/mihai/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_vector.h
Information:(729) (Unknown) In file included
/home/mihai/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_bvector.h
Error:(37, 29) error: 'CHAR_BIT' was not declared in this scope
Information:(110, 24) in expansion of macro '_STLP_WORD_BIT'
Error:(37, 29) error: 'CHAR_BIT' was not declared in this scope
Information:(118, 19) in expansion of macro '_STLP_WORD_BIT'
Error:(37, 29) error: 'CHAR_BIT' was not declared in this scope
Information:(133, 19) in expansion of macro '_STLP_WORD_BIT'
Error:(37, 29) error: 'CHAR_BIT' was not declared in this scope
Information:(143, 12) in expansion of macro '_STLP_WORD_BIT'
Error:(37, 29) error: 'CHAR_BIT' was not declared in this scope
Information:(298, 24) in expansion of macro '_STLP_WORD_BIT'
Error:(37, 29) error: 'CHAR_BIT' was not declared in this scope
Information:(404, 47) in expansion of macro '_STLP_WORD_BIT'
/usr/local/include/boost/signals2/signal.hpp
Information:(22) (Unknown) In file included
/usr/local/include/boost/move/utility.hpp
Information:(28) (Unknown) In file included
/usr/local/include/boost/signals2/connection.hpp
Error:(164, 62) error: 'move' is not a member of 'std'
Information:(164, 62) suggested alternatives:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/move/move.hpp:32:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/variant/detail/move.hpp:28,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/variant/detail/initializer.hpp:23,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:30,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/signals2/slot_base.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/signals2/detail/tracked_objects_visitor.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/signals2/slot.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/signals2/connection.hpp:23,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/signals2/signal.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/signals2.hpp:19,
                 from /home/mihai/Projects/tango-ar/cpp_plane_fitting_example/app/src/main/jni/tango-plane-fitting/localisation_interface.hpp:7,
                 from /home/mihai/Projects/tango-ar/cpp_plane_fitting_example/app/src/main/jni/tango-plane-fitting/Floor.h:9,
                 from /home/mihai/Projects/tango-ar/cpp_plane_fitting_example/app/src/main/jni/Floor.cpp:5:
/usr/local/include/boost/move/algorithm.hpp:55:6: note:   'boost::move'
Error:(173, 33) error: 'move' is not a member of 'std'
Information:(173, 33) suggested alternatives:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/move/move.hpp:32:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/variant/detail/move.hpp:28,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/variant/detail/initializer.hpp:23,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:30,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/signals2/slot_base.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/signals2/detail/tracked_objects_visitor.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/signals2/slot.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/signals2/connection.hpp:23,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/signals2/signal.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/signals2.hpp:19,
                 from /home/mihai/Projects/tango-ar/cpp_plane_fitting_example/app/src/main/jni/tango-plane-fitting/localisation_interface.hpp:7,
                 from /home/mihai/Projects/tango-ar/cpp_plane_fitting_example/app/src/main/jni/tango-plane-fitting/Floor.h:9,
                 from /home/mihai/Projects/tango-ar/cpp_plane_fitting_example/app/src/main/jni/Floor.cpp:5:
/usr/local/include/boost/move/algorithm.hpp:55:6: note:   'boost::move'...
```

This is my `app/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "24"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.projecttango.examples.cpp.planefitting"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel 19
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 19
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"

            buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-android.txt"))

                    ndk {
                        debuggable = true
                    }
                }
                debug {
                    debuggable = true
                }
            }
        }

        ndk {
            moduleName "tango-plane-fitting"
            stl "stlport_static"
            cppFlags.add("-I${file("src/main/jni/tango-plane-fitting/")}".toString())
            cppFlags.add("-I${file("/usr/local/include/")}".toString())
            cppFlags.add("-I${file("/usr/include/")}".toString())
            cppFlags.add("-I${file("/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/")}".toString())
            cppFlags.add("-I${file("/usr/local/include/eigen3/")}".toString())
            cppFlags.add("-I${file("../../tango_client_api/include/")}".toString())
            cppFlags.add("-I${file("../../third_party/glm/")}".toString())
            cppFlags.add("-I${file("../../third_party/glm/glm/")}".toString())
            cppFlags.add("-I${file("../../tango_gl/include/")}".toString())
            cppFlags.add("-I${file("../../tango_support_api/include/")}".toString())
            cppFlags.add("-std=c++11")
            cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
            ldLibs.addAll(['GLESv2', 'log', 'android'])
        }
        sources {
            main {
                java {
                    source {
                        srcDir "src"
                    }
                }
                jni
                {
                    source
                    {
                        include "jni_interface.cc"
                        include "plane_fitting.cc"
                        include "plane_fitting_application.cc"
                        include "point_cloud_renderer.cc"
                        include "../../../tango_gl/bounding_box.cc"
                        include "../../../tango_gl/camera.cc "
                        include "../../../tango_gl/conversions.cc "
                        include "../../../tango_gl/cube.cc "
                        include "../../../tango_gl/drawable_object.cc "
                        include "../../../tango_gl/mesh.cc "
                        include "../../../tango_gl/shaders.cc "
                        include "../../../tango_gl/transform.cc "
                        include "../../../tango_gl/util.cc "
                        include "../../../tango_gl/video_overlay.cc"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}
task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
    Properties properties = new Properties()
    properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
    def ndkbuild = properties.getProperty('ndk.dir', null)+"/ndk-build"
    commandLine ndkbuild, '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':cpp_example_util')
}
```

`build.gradle`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-rc1'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove these lines:

```
        cppFlags.add("-I${file("/usr/local/include/")}".toString())
        cppFlags.add("-I${file("/usr/include/")}".toString())
        cppFlags.add("-I${file("/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/")}".toString())
        cppFlags.add("-I${file("/usr/local/include/eigen3/")}".toString())
```

Those are the headers for your system, not for Android. They are not compatible.

Beyond that, you're trying to use C++11 features but using stlport. Stlport does not support C++11.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did remove the lines, and commented out stlport, but I am facing the same errors

Comment: You can't just remove stlport, you need to replace it with an STL that does have support for C++11 (I don't know for sure what gradle defaults to, but I think it's nothing): https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html

Comment: Tried gnustl_static (or shared) - they both support c++11, but the errors are exactly the same

Comment: Could you update your original post to contain your current build files and errors? I would have expected gnustl to work.