# Android Studio 2.2.3 cannot find <vector>

Tags: android, android-ndk, cmake, ndk-build

### Configuration

**Operating system**: Ubuntu 16.04

**Android Studio Version**: 2.2.3

### Key code

`~/project/build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
      repositories {
          jcenter()
      }
      dependencies {
          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
      }
  }
  ...
```

`~/project/library/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        ...

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang',
                        '-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static'
                     // I also tried '-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_shared', result is same
            }
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

`~/project/app/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
    compile project(':library')
    ...
}
```

`~/project/settings.gradle`

```
include ':app', ':library'
```

`~/project/library/src/main/cpp/test.h`:

```
#include <vector>   // vector is red, says "cannot find vector"
#include <stdint.h>

class test {

private:
    std::vector<int32_t> array;  // std is red, says "can't resolve container std"
};
```

#### Description of problem

In file `~/project/library/src/main/cpp/test.h`, `vector` in `#include <vector>` is red.
When I move the mouse over it, it will popup a window which says `Cannot find 'vector'`.
`std` in `std::vector<int32_t>` is also red. I move the mouse over it and it says `Can't resolve container 'std'`.

This project has no compile error. It can be compiled successfully and installed on my phone. The problem is it has a syntax error. I don't have code completion on some variables, like `array` in `test.h`.

#### Some information I find

I imported project [teapots](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/teapots) which contains `#include <vector>`.
Android Studio did resolve `vector` and `std` symbol for this project.

#### My question

What did I do wrong? Why does project [teapots](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/teapots) not have this problem?
What's the key difference between my project and `teapots` that makes the latter one able to resolve `vector` and `std` but mine not?

---

### Update

I created a new project in Android Studio. In step 1 of the new project wizard, I checked `include C++ Support`. In the last step, I kept the default `Toolchain Default` for `C++ Standard` option. After I clicked the `finish` button, Android Studio automatically created the file `native-lib.cpp` for me. I added code `#include <vector>` in line 3 in this file. This time Android Studio resolved symbol `vector` correctly. Then I created a new module library `mylibrary` for this project, and in there I added a `cpp` folder and `test.h` and it also resolved the symbol `vector`(`mylibrary` module's `build.gradle` had been correctly added CMake stuff by me). But my problem is I need to add `vector` to my existing project, and my existing project can't resolve the symbol `vector`.

Comment: does vector have a file extension??

Comment: no extension. @codeMan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. I didn't include the C++ file `test.h` in `CMakeLists.txt`. Once I included it into `CMakeLists.txt` `add_library` parentheses and synced project, the red syntax error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look here - this is a good solution, guiding through the makefile and the code itself: [Can't include C++ headers like vector in Android NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893403/cant-include-c-headers-like-vector-in-android-ndk). I have used this in the past and it helped me.

Comment: My problem is more like [Maksim Dmitriev's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893403/cant-include-c-headers-like-vector-in-android-ndk#answer-20565845). My project have no compile error. It can compiled successful and installed on my phone. Problem is it has syntax error. I don't have code completion on some variable, like `array` in my `test.h` example.

Answer (score 0):

bu2zhouzhu answer is correct. i just expalin it.

problem in file.
whenever you add .cpp file, you need to update in CMakeLists.txt like this

```
add_library(libraryName SHARED
file_name1.cpp
file_name2.cpp)
```

In my case.

```
add_library( native-lib SHARED
         native-lib.cpp
         webp_engine.cpp
         webp_link.cpp)
```

native-lib  --> library name(default name,i don't edit it).

webp_engine.cpp --> i created file.

webp_link.cpp  --> i craeted file