# Using the STL with Android NDK C++

Tags: android, c++, stl, android-ndk

I am trying to use the STL in an Android NDK C++ File. I try to use map, vector and various other stl classes and I cannot compile it because it doesn't find the files.

My classes header starts with:

```
#pragma once
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
```

and I get following error messages:

```
2>  In file included from jni/../../Classes/Assist/Test.cpp:1:
2>  jni/../../Classes/Assist/Test.h:2:15: error: map: No such file or directory
2>  jni/../../Classes/Assist/Test.h:3:20: error: iostream: No such file or directory
2>  jni/../../Classes/Assist/Test.h:4:21: error: stdexcept: No such file or directory
2>  jni/../../Classes/Assist/Test.h:5:18: error: vector: No such file or directory
2>  jni/../../Classes/Assist/Test.h:6:15: error: set: No such file or directory
2>  jni/../../Classes/Assist/Test.h:7:16: error: list: No such file or directory
2>  jni/../../Classes/Assist/Test.h:8:21: error: algorithm: No such file or directory
2>  In file included from jni/../../Classes/Assist/Test.cpp:1:
```

I read various posts and tried "APP_STL := stlport_static" and "APP_STL := gnustl_static" in an application.mk file but it didn't work.

Does anyone know how I can get this to work ?

Comment: My advice is to stick with the Java API.  Honestly :(

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893403/cant-include-c-headers-like-vector-in-android-ndk/4931170#4931170 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650963/ustl-or-stlport-for-android will help you.

Comment: What version of the NDK are you using?

Comment: I am using the NDK r7 and unfortunately none of the 2 links posted by Yury work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the mistake was a somehow broken NDK. I reinstalled it (delete, unzip) and now it works.

Answer (score 43):

I had the same problem, and then realized that  I need to put:
APP_STL := stlport_static

in Application.mk, not Android.mk ... doh

Then I needed to add:
${ANDROID_NDK_ROOT}\sources\cxx-stl\stlport\stlport

to the include paths in eclipse to make it not complain in the UI about errors

Comment: Sorry did not work for me. The same build works fine in Linux env,but fails in Windows. Still looking for an answer.

Comment: its better to put c++_shared so as to include libcpp_shared.so in the apk